# Is there a way to retry a time sensitive step in Azure Devops a number of times?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

All the answers I've found are rather dated, so I'm wondering if there is now a way to retry a step after failure?

For example:

```
Step - Install X
Step - Test if X is installed. 
           If failed, wait 1 minute, then retry two more times before total failure.
```

The issue I have, is that the second step is a third party extension, so I cannot use bash or a script to do it with an internal loop in the step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible yet. However, this is on [roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline)

[image]

[Automatic retries for a task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-195-update#automatic-retries-for-a-task) was added and it can be used in this way:

```yaml
- task: <name of task>
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: <max number of retries>
   ...
```

however `The failing task is retried immediately.` so there is no way to define wait time.

Comment: I see! Thank you. :)